# Page Tree Loading Time out in Workspace mode

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

In one of my project I'm facing issues with loading backend page tree. It shows always system connection error. This issue only happen in the workspace mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a installation with many entries in workspace. I solved it by adding this line in typo3conf/extTables.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/tree/pagetree/class.t3lib_tree_pagetree_dataprovider.php']['postProcessCollections'] = array();
```

Comment: This may or may not help but using extTables.php is strongly discouraged as it is deprecated since Version 7.3 and this question is tagged as version 7.6, see https://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3.CMS/Releases/7.3/Deprecation#Deprecation:_.2365344_-_typo3conf.2FextTables.php_deprecated